# Should we seed the site with questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

Some communities has done this on Stack Overflow to seed the site with content for particular topics.

For instance, should we take some recent threads from [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) that have a large number of views and create questions w/ answers for those topics?

Other possible sources for seed content?

Answer (score 5):

I think arbitrarily seed this site is not very effective. The problem is that information might be outdated, irrelevant or false. I think, if there are issues that are still current and need to be solved, it might make sense, but those issues will probably come up anyway.

Comment: Agreed. The content would have to be quality-controlled for sure.