# Is it appropriate to Ask question and provide an Answer to topic which is not mentioned?

Tags: discussion, answers

Hi,
My question is about when somebody have a solution (e.g., specific problem which affect a couple of people), but nobody ask for different reasons. This question is similar as [Should we seed the site with questions and answers?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/107/should-we-seed-the-site-with-questions-and-answers) but shift the focus to share up to date knowledge.

Sincerely,
Ivaylo Raynov

Comment: I cannot understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're asking if it's ok to ask a question and provide your own answer. From the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq):

> It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm disappointed you didn't answer this question yourself! ;)

In all seriousness though, I think that there is a difference between asking and answering a question just because it's not already covered on the site, compared to asking a question and then stumbling across the answer while investigating it yourself (before any other users have been able to answer it).