# I figured out the answer to my question, should I remove it or post it.

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it appropriate to Ask question and provide an Answer to topic which is not mentioned?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/678/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-question-and-provide-an-answer-to-topic-which-is-not-men)

I just posted a question and a little while after posting I found out the answer.

Should I leave the question on there, wait the 8 hours to answer it myself (if nobody else has before that)... It took me some googling and searching to figure out, so I'd like to think that a well formulated question and answer still have reason to exist.

Or should I delete it?

I'm not really sure what the protocol is here.

Comment: if you feel the question and answer would be useful to others, I would post it and keep it. If it is "whoops, the power cord was unplugged" then.. no :)